# Label placement in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I want to have the label arrows look that I get when using `axis lines=center` but I also want my x and y label to be on the outside of the plot and not inside the actual plot area. I have been looking through that huge manual for a while now but I am not making any progress. How can I get this?

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=1,xmin=0,xmax=1,
xlabel=$\mathit{foo}$,
ylabel=$\mathit{bar}$,
axis lines=center
]
\addplot[color=black, fill=black, fill opacity=0.5] coordinates {
(0.0,0.0)
(0.05, 0.3)
(0.1,0.5)
(0.2,0.7)
(0.3,0.8)
(0.4,0.9)
(0.5,0.92)
(0.6,0.93)
(0.7,0.95)
(0.8,0.99)
(1.0,1.0)
(1.0,0.0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I want the labels like this:

[image]

But the axes like this:

[image]

Comment: You want your second graph with the axis labels outside but not centered as in the first one, did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes! (And then I have to add some more text here because comments can't be that short...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that, you should use `axis lines=left` instead of `axis lines=center`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0,ymax=1,xmin=0,xmax=1,
xlabel=$\mathit{foo}$,
ylabel=$\mathit{bar}$,
axis lines=center
]
\addplot[color=black, fill=black, fill opacity=0.5] coordinates {
(0.0,0.0)
(0.05, 0.3)
(0.1,0.5)
(0.2,0.7)
(0.3,0.8)
(0.4,0.9)
(0.5,0.92)
(0.6,0.93)
(0.7,0.95)
(0.8,0.99)
(1.0,1.0)
(1.0,0.0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```